# Question incorrectly moved to Serverfault

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration, new-users, serverfault

I have a [question](https://serverfault.com/q/292176/25528) that I don't believe should have been moved to Serverfault.

### Update0

Here's what the faq states are appropriate topics for questions on Serverfault:

- Servers
- Networks
- Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace

Each of these is vaguely relevant in the same way that `ssh` is vaguely relevant to networking, and computers are relevant to programming. The faq for Stackoverflow states:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- matters that are unique to the programming profession

Clearly all of these apply to this question. I don't think it's appropriate to move questions to Serverfault just for using the words "script", "ssh", and "host".

Comment: Could you explain why you think it was a better fit on SO and/or why you think it does not fit on SF?

Comment: Agree with @popular.  It isn't clear how it is programming related.

Comment: The thing is, 5 different people agreed that it belonged on SF - and you got some good answers out of it.

Comment: Given that so many disagree with keeping it on SO, *and* that you got good answers from the migration, I wonder why you feel this way? There seems to be an element of snobbishness at times with people taking a migration as a suggestion their question isn't good enough. That isn't the case at all; a migration is supposed to be about finding the best place to get good answers for that question, a mechanism that seems to have worked for your question.

Comment: It ISN'T clear? It doesn't get any clearer. There are also number of precedents for similar questions that have been moved BACK to SO. My reasoning is simple. SF is a backwater, my question is clearly related to programming as per the SO FAQ, and I want it answered on SO.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a fit for SF to me.  The question is how to invoke an interpreter through SSH.  To me that's an OS level thing that is appropriate for SF.  Getting the shebang hooked in via SSH is OS level as well.